# Macro to copy a row, insert it into next blank row and clear contents

Tags: vba, excel

I need the VBA code to do this:

> Copy a row
>
> insert the copied row into the next blank row
>
> clear the contents (without deleting the formula or data validation that's in the cells).

I'm currently using this, but it only inserts the row directly underneath the active cell and doesn't clear the contents.

```
Sub InsertCopyRow()

   ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert
   ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).EntireRow

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "without deleting the formula", do you want to say "formatting" (red/blue etc), or really formula (=A1+C5 etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions, pick the one you like:

Use Cut instead of Copy:

```
Sub InsertCopyRow()

 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
 ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

End Sub
```

Or clear the contents of the original row after copying:

```
Sub InsertCopyRow()

 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
 ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
 ActiveCell.EntireRow.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, the row being copied needs to remain in place, with all cell values and formatting/formula. Thanks

Comment: OK, I don't get it then. In your question, you say "clear the contents". Where do you want to clear the content from? So you don't want to insert a new row? You want the code to find the next blank row? Can you add  an example to your question?